# How to set up a simple forward proxy server?

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

I am trying to check a script that have to runs through a proxy server (for IP rotation). I want to set up a simple forward proxy server in my local to test it.

I may be googling it wrong. But I am struggling to make it possible.

I have checked:

- https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy

But looks like it is more a docker service discovery, so what I understand is called a *reverse proxy*.

I am checking nginx:

- https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx

But all example configurations I find to set nginx as a proxy make reference to also redirect concrete requests to different servers, so also *reverse proxy* configurations.

How to set up a simple forward proxy (ideally using a docker image so it is easy to reproduce same set up in production) that I can make a request like this?:

```
curl http://httpbin.org/get -x localhost:9080
```

Where `localhost:9080` is where my proxy is

Comment: For developing Mitmproxy may be of interest to you. It is not a simple proxy but it is pretty easy to install and run as it is Python based and it has the ability to inspect the HTTP calls and it's responses.

Comment: `nginx` is regularly used as a proxy solution in Docker environments. Have you tried setting it up? What sort of issues did you encounter? For what you're describing, it sounds like normal Docker port publishing would suffice; are you sure you need a proxy in the first place?

Comment: @larsks nginx sounds like a possible solution as I say in the question, I haven't tried to set it up because I don't find any documentation of how to set a proxy as I need. All the proxy configurations I find are related to configure what I understand is a `reverse proxy` which is redirecting concrete requests to concrete servers.. I just need to redirect all the traffic through this proxy. I also have tried the `nginx-proxy` docker image that I mention in my question but I found this issue: https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/1182#issuecomment-846616731